# my native android project shows an error "05-13 14:00:09.930: A//system/bin/app_process(5774): stack corruption detected: aborted"

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my latest project , I use two native libraries.Some time it shows an error code in log cat

```
"05-13 14:00:09.930: A//system/bin/app_process(5774): stack corruption detected: aborted",
```

But sometimes it work properly.I dont know how to solve this problem any one please help me.

Comment: The logcat output should also show a stack dump indicating which thread and method it was in when the stack corruption was detected.  Do you see that?

Comment: "05-15 10:23:22.379: A//system/bin/app_process(8103): stack corruption detected: aborted
05-15 10:23:23.527: D/libEGL(8271): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-15 10:23:23.543: D/libEGL(8271): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-15 10:23:23.551: D/libEGL(8271): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-15 10:23:23.699: D/OpenGLRenderer(8271): Enabling debug mode 0"  these are my logcat output